# Importing salt causes flask to output nothing in the terminal

Tags: python, flask, salt-stack

Suppose I have the following `foo.py` file:

```
#import salt
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def slash():
    return 'foo'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

If I run `python foo.py` I get this output and everything is fine:

```
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/
 * Restarting with reloader
```

Now if I un-comment the `import salt` line and run `python foo.py` I get nothing in the terminal, although I can confirm with curl that my web app is indeed running. Is there any conflict between Salt Stack API and Flask, or have I perhaps discovered a bug?

I'm using Flask 0.10.1 and Salt 2014.7.0 with Python 2.7.6 inside a virtualenv.

**EDIT:** I found out what this is about, though I'm still not sure what the solution is. Salt calls `logging.setLoggerClass(SaltLoggingClass)` as part of its initialization and so `SaltLoggingClass` is used from then on as our logging class, even in other modules.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay I found out what is going on here and I also found a workaround. As I said on my last edit, this is Salt's doing as already reported [here](https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/4994). The workaround is to initialize logging yourself before importing Salt. Something like this:

```
import sys
import logging
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stdout, level=logging.DEBUG, format="%(message)s")

# Now we can import salt.
import salt
```

I don't think this is the best decision on Salt's part, but we have to do with what we got!

Comment: @ReutSharabani Thanks for reminding me. I had to wait for two days to be able to accept my own answer, but I was about to forget.